# I'm trying to write a test that makes sure that there is content in a text file, but it keeps failing and I'm not sure what the problem is?

Tags: testing, elixir

So I am trying to write a test in my Elixir project that will make sure that there is content in a txt file. However, each time I try to phrase the test differently in the code, or when I change a function, it always fails. I'm very confused, what should I do?

I've tried to use the `Enum.count/1` function, but the compiler tells me that I have a bad function. Then I tried adding an assert command to the `Enum.count/1` function, thinking that maybe I needed to add that, but then the compiler said that assert_Enum does not exist.

```rb
def read_memberlist do
  load_from_file "test/memberemaillist.txt"
end

test "that there is one member email in memberlist.txt file" do
  ClientEmailCleaner.read_memberlist()
  |> Enum.count(1)
  |> assert_Enum.count
end
```

I expected that when I wrote `Enum.count`, then it would count the content in the text file. However, it failed and the compiler said that there was a "bad function error". Next, I tried to add an assert command but the compiler told me that the command​ that I wrote, "assert_Enum.count" did not exist.

Comment: Where is `load_from_file` defined? Understanding what that function returns will help guide an assertion about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your trying to use Enum.count to test whether or not there is content in a txt file. If your txt file is empty File.read! will return an empty string "". Perhaps you could write some idiomatic Elixir in the form of

```
{:ok, content}, {:error, reason}
```

Your Module can be written something like this.

```
defmodule ClientEmailCleaner do

  def read_memberlist do
    memberlist = File.read!("test/member_email_list.txt")
    read_memberlist(memberlist)
  end

  defp read_memberlist(memberlist) when memberlist == "" do
    {:error, "File is empty"}
  end

  defp read_memberlist(memberlist) do
    {:ok, memberlist}
  end

end
```

And then in your test file you could write a test that covers both cases. It will pass if txt file contains content or not.

```
  test "returns content or error from memberlist.txt" do
    case ClientEmailCleaner.read_memberlist do
      {:ok, content} ->
        assert content

      {:error, reason} ->
        assert reason
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert_Enum.count` is somewhat unknown to the compiler. Also, the following code is invalid, because you are trying to effectively pass two parameters while `Enum.count/1` has arity `1`:

```
ClientEmailCleaner.read_memberlist()
|> Enum.count(1)
```

The above is fully equivalent to `Enum.count(ClientEmailCleaner.read_memberlist(), 1)`.

What you probably need is:

```
assert 1 == Enum.count(ClientEmailCleaner.read_memberlist())
```